# Are there style checker for Ruby code as JSLint for javascript

Tags: ruby, code-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find an actively developed lint tool for Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805146/where-can-i-find-an-actively-developed-lint-tool-for-ruby)

I'm new to Ruby and impressed about it's super flexibility.
As a beginner it is hard for me to differentiate good coding style and bad(even dangerous) coding style.
So is there any tool that can automatically check the current coding style for me while I'm coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's this tool named [rails_best_practices](https://github.com/flyerhzm/rails_best_practices) but it's Rails-specific, not general Ruby, and it acts more as a guideline.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a read:

https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide