# How to integrate rubocop with Rake?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, rake, rubocop

[rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) is a code style checker for Ruby. A similar tool to rubocop, Cane, can be [integrated with Rake](https://github.com/square/cane#integrating-with-rake). I prefer rubocop to Cane since rubocop makes checks based on the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) and it seems to [spot more problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15007900/789593). To automate the process of style checking I would like to integrate rubocop with Rake so that the build fails if code quality is lacking.

Gem already supports [adding tests](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#writing-tests) to packages via Rake. I would like to do the same with style checks so that style checks are run along with the tests. How can I do this?

If it helps to start with a Rakefile here is one:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8; mode: ruby -*-

require 'bundler/gem_tasks'
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.test_files = FileList['test/unit/test*.rb']
end

desc 'Run tests'
task default: :test
```

Answer (score -13, accepted):

I would recommend shelling out to the rubocop program. It's the simplest solution. Just add this to your Rakefile:

```
task test: :rubocop

task :rubocop do
  sh 'rubocop'
end
```

Comment: The below solution is probably better - using `RuboCop::RakeTask`

Answer (score 77):

As of version `0.10.0` rubocop contain a custom rake task that you can use. Just put the following in your `Rakefile`

```
require 'rubocop/rake_task'

RuboCop::RakeTask.new
```

Make sure to use upper-case 'R' and 'C' or you will get a NameError.

Comment: The code of the rake-task can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/rake_task.rb)

Answer (score 35):

I highly recommend,

```
require 'rubocop/rake_task'

RuboCop::RakeTask.new(:rubocop) do |t|
  t.options = ['--display-cop-names']
end
```

This uses the rubocop's own rake tasks and allows you to pass options if you like.

Comment: How to add more then one option? e.g. `--display-cop-names --format markdown -o rubocop.md`

Answer (score 2):

You will probably find https://github.com/yujinakayama/guard-rubocop useful if you use Guard for your RSpec tests. It enables Rubocop to give you instant feedback as soon as you save the file,  along with your test results.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar myself, and ended up looking in the internal source code of the `RuboCop::RakeTask` here:

https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/blob/a34a1c2c2dd1fa6d90ffd06c183421a495a0717c/lib/rubocop/rake_task.rb#L40-L43

```rb
      require 'rubocop'

      cli = CLI.new
      puts 'Running RuboCop...' if verbose
      result = cli.run(options)
      abort('RuboCop failed!') if result.nonzero? && fail_on_error
```

You can actually invoke similar code directly in your own codebase / rake task.

I ended up writing a little wrapper module I can call to, with some default flags that I always want to be applied:

```rb
module RubocopCli
  def self.run!(*args)
    require "rubocop"
    cli = RuboCop::CLI.new
    result = cli.run(["--display-cop-names", "--force-exclusion", "--fail-level", "autocorrect", *args])
    raise "RubocopCli.run! Linting failed." if result.nonzero?
  end
end
```

Then you can call it with additional args from any task, or app code, like:

```rb
files_to_lint = %w[lib/whatever.rb spec/lib/whatever_spec.rb]
RubocopCli.run!("--auto-correct", *files_to_lint)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can shell out via Rake with the options you prefer:

```
  desc 'Run Rubocop with options'
  task rubocop: :environment do
    sh 'bundle exec rubocop -D --format offenses --format progress || true'
  end
```

I then recommend modifying the default task to include the output. The trick is to clear the task and then add back what you want. Note the need to end with `|| true` so that an error from Rubocop will not prevent the next task from running. Here's what I do, which also uses parallel tests:

```
task(:default).clear.enhance ['parallel:parallel_prepare', 'parallel:spec',
                              'parallel:features', 'lint:rubocop',
                              'lint:rails_best_practices']
```