# How to pipe the output of shell command to from a rake task

Tags: shell, rake

[How to integrate rubocop with Rake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008751/how-to-integrate-rubocop-with-rake)

I would like to pipe the output of the above shell command to ("sh rubocop") to a text file, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you paste a sample output ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate rubocop with Rake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008751/how-to-integrate-rubocop-with-rake)