# Gem for formatting rails source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a gem I can install that creates a rake task that, when run, beautifies up my ruby code? Indentation, rouge line breaks, that sort of thing?

Comment: If you don't find an answer to your question, I would recommend looking into [Vim for Rubyists](http://www.vimninjas.com/2012/08/28/vim-for-rubyists-part-1/), and start using an editor.  Why overload the application with a gem, why not fix the programmer's editor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103874/coding-style-checker-or-code-formatter-for-ruby-rails - you can see some gems listed in the answers. I also highly recommend just using an editor like Vim or Sublime to format the code.